# Set a variable to the smaller of two other variables

Tags: xslt

When I try to use the code below I get a duplicate variable error because variables are immutable.  How do I set the smaller of the two variables (`$nextSubPartPos` and `$nextQuestionStemPos`) as my new variable (`$nextQuestionPos`)?

```
        <xsl:variable name="nextQuestionPos"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$nextSubPartPos &lt; $nextQuestionStemPos">
                <xsl:variable name="nextQuestionPos" select="$nextSubPartPos"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="nextQuestionPos" select="$nextSubPartPos"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't close the xsl:variable node in the first line. That is, take the / out of it, then put an `</xsl:variable>` after `</xsl:choose>`. Next, change the `<xsl:variable>` nodes inside the choose to `<xsl:value-of>` nodes.

That is, you want to set the value of the variable with the choose. There are two ways to set the value of a variable. One is the select attribute, the other is the inner text of the node.

```
<xsl:variable name="nextQuestionPos">
    <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$nextSubPartPos &lt; $nextQuestionStemPos">
               <xsl:value-of select="$nextSubPartPos"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="$nextSubPartPos"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 5):

A compact XPath 1.0 expression that evaluates to the smaller value is:

**$v1*($v2 >= $v1) + $v2*($v1 > $v2)**

where the $v1 and $v2 variables contain the values to be compared.

So, an elegant one-liner XSLT 1.0 solution will look like this:

**<xsl:variable name="v3" select="$v1*($v2 >= $v1) +$v2*($v1 > $v2)"/>**

It is easier to define a variable as required in XSLT 2.0:

One can use either the following (more readable) one-liner:

**if($v2 gt $v1)

                then $v1

                else $v2**

Or the more compact:

**min(($v1, $v2))**

Comment: @yegor256, Agreed, for XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `min` function:

```
<xsl:variable name="a" select="42" />
<xsl:variable name="b" select="23" />
<xsl:variable name="x" select="min(($a,$b))" />
```

In your example, replace the entire code with:

```
<xsl:variable name="nextQuestionPos" select="min(($nextSubPartPos,$nextQuestionStemPos))" />
```

Saxon implements min in the global namespace. Other processors may require a namespace, the correct one (usually denoted `fn`) is `http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions` .

Comment: This solves the immediate problem, but doesn't address the larger question of how to implement complex logic - perhaps logic too complex for XPath - to form a variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in XSLT are immutable. This has tripped me up so many times.

Comment: Is there any way to get the larger of the two?

Comment: @joe, yes. Replace min with max in my answer or < and > in the question

Comment: Yes, but that's a new question. :)  See my answer, it provides more compact and ellegant XPath 1.0 solution and two different XPath 2.0 solutions.